# Will GCM crash Android apps in 2.1?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented push notifications in my Android app (registered a broadcast receiver, etc.) using the android support v7 library to get it working in 2.3.

I know that GCM is not supported in Android 2.1, but what if i leave the minSDKversion in the manifest at 7? When running the app on a 2.1 simulator, I get logcat statements similar to "Google Play services is missing", but no crash. Is this reliable enough proof that Android 2.1 devices will not crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will crash on devices.

"Google Play services is missing" shows on all android simulator if you are using any Google Service.

Comment: I wonder if this can be handled with conditional logic to check device version? (if version < 2.3, dont attempt to register with GCM)...

Comment: Yes, you can handle this.